# Adding Image on Paths

Tags: wpf, image, path

My problem is I have paths to draw cities and I want to put images inside these cities I cant put Image inside `<Path>` tags.

Why cant I write such code? any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a canvas or a custom panel with x,y placements and add images to the correct coordinates (same coordinates used by path).

You can query the path nodes to find their coordinates if you don't know them.

Edit: Since your window size changes and coordinates "stretch" accordingly, you **will** need to implement a custom panel. - Inherit from Panel and override measure and arrange methods as in this example: http://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html

Your custom panel should have X and Y attached dependency properties (like Canvas does) only that methods should use either relative coordinates (0 to 1) instead of (0 to width and 0 to height) or divide by original path width and height to normalize to coordinates.

Comment: Coordinates always changes according to the current window size so it  does not work.

Comment: By the way how do I query the path nodes can you write example code her eI would be glad

Comment: Sorry, you might have to use a custom path too - the regular path doesn't seem separable to sections. Could you explain a bit more about how you get the path?

Comment: I solved it thanx just used regular canvas.Top and Canvas.Left because the paths are in the same canvas it resized with them

Comment: With a custom panel you can also control how the images resize, however, the basic canvas is an OK starting point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Path.Fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.fill.aspx) for this. Use an [`ImageBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush.aspx).

On a side-note, what can be written as child node/s of a element is determined by the [`ContentPropertyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute.aspx), for a `ContentControl` it points to the `Content` property for example (as can be seen in the `Syntax` section of [its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx)).

Comment: Property Fill does not support images ? + I already want to put images on a filled paths. Can you send code I would be glad

Comment: @albatross: I said you should use an `ImageBrush`, not an `Image`; anyway, for more complex things like fill & image you could use a [`VisualBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx) (with that you can use controls). And no, i will not "send code", read the docs, i even linked all that are relevant.

Comment: Ok I tried it but I dont want to fill the image I just want to put an image with its original point. I recognize that I actually want to get the canvas x y coordinates of cities and put my image on that coordinates. But from path I cant access the center point? How can I get the citie's x-y coordinates on canvas?

Comment: @albatross Ask that in a separate question. This question was answered. You can either add images as I suggested or "color in" the path with an imagebrush as HB suggested.