# image integration in setter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have used path to create a custom object as:

```
  <Path Style="{StaticResource ABC_Style}" ToolTip="object ABC"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center"></Path>
```

ABC_Style definition is:

```
<Style x:Key="ABC_Style" TargetType="Path">
    <Setter ..../>
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value .../>
</Style>
```

Now, I have to assign a mesh image into the object (as content).

Questions:

1. Is there any way to integrate an image into it?
2. if so, is it possible to avoid picture from getting stretched?

Thanks.

Comment: See this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9670109/620360).

Comment: Don't you mean to *fill* the Path with an image, i.e. to set the `Fill` property with an `ImageBrush`?

Answer (score 1):

What I can think is, you can create a drawing Brush something like

```
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="image.jpg" x:Key="imageBrush" />
    <DrawingBrush x:Key="ThatchBackground" Viewport="0,0,50,50" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource imageBrush}">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50"/>
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
```

and Set the path fill like below

```
<Path Fill="{StaticResource ThatchBackground}">
```

I got this from this tutorial http://wpfplayground.blogspot.com/2011/09/texture-background-in-wpf.html

Comment: There is no need at all for the DrawingBrush. Simply set `Viewport="0,0,50,50"`, `ViewportUnits="Absolute"`, `Stretch="Fill"` and `TileMode="Tile"` at the ImageBrush and use that as Fill: `<Path Fill="{StaticResource imageBrush}"/>`. This is possible because ImageBrush is also a TileBrush.